# How can I group by name?

Tags: r, aggregation

I am trying to summarize this dataset by grouping by name (Almeria, Ath Bilbao,...) and have the sum of its corresponding values in column 2 (HalfTimeResult) and 3 (FullTimeResult). I tried with the aggregate function but have not been able to obtain the right output.

Something that would look like this:

[image]

This is the dataset that I am working with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the columns you wanted to aggregate are the only columns in your data.frame, then you can use a formula in the `aggregate()` function like this:

```
aggregate(. ~ HomeTeam, data = mydata, FUN = sum)
```

Here, you need the `data =` argument because you are referring to columns in the data.frame called "mydata". The `.` notation means that you are aggregating (summing) all other columns by the column "HomeTeam".